# Changing a Item in a listView on a click

Tags: android, listview

I want to make a `ListView`, when you long click on an item, the item will be added to the buttons: delete and update (only the clicked item):

So I have made a `ListView` in my `MainLayout`:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/neighborhood"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/allAddresses"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AddresSearch" />
```

and a Custom ListView Item lay out, which contains 3 TextViews:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/button_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".passItemView">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:text="cv"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/house"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/house"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="cvc"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="cv"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/num"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and this layout is conneted to a class "passItemView", and there, what I did is that on longClick on the layout it will add 2 button (or even just will make a toast)
But it does nothing.

```
public class passItemView extends AppCompatActivity {

Button delete = new Button(this);
Button update = new Button(this);
ConstraintLayout btnLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pass_item_view);


    btnLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.button_layout);
    btnLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(passItemView.this,"Toast it",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            btnLayout.addView((delete));
            btnLayout.addView((update));

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Thank you for your Help.

Comment: Why are you using listview still ? RecyclerView is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

use an boolean value (ex : showButtons)  and initialize set it false for all items.
when you clicked someitem make items showButtons variable true and notifydatasetchange (reload lsitview) again.